# make without running any recipes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following really silly makefiles:

```
# makefile
foo :
    @$(MAKE) -C other
```

```
# other/makefile
bar :
    @echo HELLO
```

Nothing complicated. When I run `$make`, I get the expected:

```
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `[...]/other'
HELLO
make[1]: Leaving directory `[...]/other'
```

However, when I run `make -pn`, my output leads with:

```
# GNU Make 3.82
# Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
# Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
# This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
# There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
make -C other
# GNU Make 3.82
# Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
# Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
# This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
# There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
# make[1]: Entering directory `[...]/other'
echo HELLO
```

Why the recursive invocation of `make` in `-pn`? I thought the recipes weren't supposed to be invoked. How do I just get `make` to dump the complete rule database, without running *anything*?

Comment: How's that related to [tag:c++] actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Lots of c++ people know make stuff well but don't follow the makefile tag and will never see a question that they would be able to answer in 30 seconds (I assume this is a fairly straightforward question).

Comment: @Barry _"Lots of c++ people know make stuff well ..."_ That doesn't justify you set the tag. There are pretty clear rules stated when it should be used or not. That's just known as _tag spamming_, sorry.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Link to said clearly stated rules?

Comment: Barry, if you seriously don't understand or believe what @πάνταῥεῖ is telling you, bring up a separate [meta] question to discuss it.  This comment thread is not the time and the place for that.

Comment: @Barry Top sentence in the c++ tag info: _"C++ is a general-purpose programming language based on C. **Use this tag for questions about code (to be) compiled with a C++ compiler**."_ (Emphasis mine)

Comment: @tripleee I don't think there's a need for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nearly link-only short answer is that the `MAKE` variable, and its appearance in recipe lines, are [treated specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) by GNU Make:

> *"Recipe lines containing MAKE are executed normally despite the presence of a flag that causes most recipes not to be run."*

That recipe line is being executed because it it contains `$(MAKE)`. Try adding other kinds of recipe lines; you will see they are not executed.

As you can see, this is for a good reason. Since you have organized your project using multiple disjoint makefiles that are recursively invoked, instead of one big rule base, in order to see the "complete rule database", you in fact have to recursively process all the makefiles. The rules from just your top-level `Makefile` are not the complete rule database.

Comment: This makes sense because even if you don't want to actually create anything, you'd like to see what all the recursive makes are going to do as well.